# What is Utnubu?

Tags: debian

Not Ubuntu,I heard it on Planet Ubuntu but google doesn't tell me anything.

It is something related to Debian.

Comment: @garbagecollector yes, apparently.

Comment: @erigami what are you talking about?

Comment: @garbagecollector There was totally a comment from you here earlier. Or I'm going crazy.

Comment: @erigami I didn't comment till you said something to me.

Comment: @garbagecollector That leaves one other option. =)

Comment: @erigami what? :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you mean [this](http://wiki.debian.org/Utnubu)?

> One of Ubuntu's activities is frequently redistributing packages originally from Debian to Ubuntu's users. Well, Utnubu is about the reverse, copying packages from Ubuntu to Debian.

I've never heard of this before. I assume it's real. =)

Answer (score 16):

Utnubu - Ubuntu spelled backwards - is an effort to package Ubuntu-specific packages for Debian. While historically most applications have been packaged by Debian developers and imported into Ubuntu, there are a growing number of applications that have been packaged directly by Ubuntu developers and which could easily be imported into Debian.

You can find out more on [the Debian wiki page](http://wiki.debian.org/Utnubu). There is also [a mailing list](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/utnubu-discuss), and, as maco pointed out, an IRC channel.

Answer (score 11):

It's the effort to work together with Debian.  Check out the #debian-ubuntu channel on OFTC